# Google Chrome constantly needs to be killed on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

This seems to be happening more and more often, up to a point where I needed to create a shortcut in my desktop to run the command to kill Chrome:

```
taskkill /T /F /IM chrome.exe
```

Operating system is Windows 10 Pro 64-bits, up-to-date, and Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit).

What happens is that, I am browsing normally, until eventually I need to open a new tab to navigate to somewhere. I type in the address or search terms and press Enter. Nothing happens, the page is just blank as if it's loading. It takes me a while to realise that "oh no it happened again". Then I proceed to kill Chrome, because closing the tab doesn't work. Every new tab will behave like this, but the tabs which were already open works fine, and I can browse perfectly on them. When it restarts, everything is fine, until the cycle repeats.

I'm asking this question here because I have never seen this behaviour before, and couldn't find any bug report on that matter.

I need help to diagnose and solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following instructions.

1. Open a new tab.
2. Enter the address chrome://flags in the address bar
3. Scroll down until you find the entry "Enable Instant Extended API Mac, Windows, Chrome OS"
4. Drop down the box and select Disabled.
5. Restart the browser.

Further more:

1. Open a new tab.
2. Enter the address chrome://flags in the address bar
3. Scroll down until you find the entry "Enable Instant Extended API Mac, Windows, Chrome OS"
4. Drop down the box and select DEFAULT
5. Restart the browser.

**Worked Solution**:

"Completely remove/uninstall Chrome and all profile files, and reinstall it. 
It seems to have worked." - Bruno Finger

Comment: Can you clarify the "furthermore"?  Do you do one sequence after the other?  The second only if the first doesn't work?

Comment: @fixer1234 First 5 steps should fix the problem. Just to re-assure and make settings to be DEFAULT, next 'further more' 5 steps will place you in the safe zone.

Comment: @SandeepVarmaGanaraju Thank you so much for your time writing your answer, but I have a problem: My browser is not in english, so I can't find the item you mentioned, due to inaccurate translations. Could you please open the Developers Tools (F12) in your Chrome while in the flags page and provide me the `id` of the `div` element containing this configuration? This way, I can jump straight to it from the address bar like `chrome://flags/#wallet-service-use-sandbox`.

Comment: @BrunoFinger Please try this URL: chrome://flags/#enable-instant-extended-api. At least click on reset everything to default in flags page by clicking on the button at top right corner. 
Just to know, have you tried resetting browser?

Comment: @SandeepVarmaGanaraju It seems this option doesn't exist anymore. Yes I tried resetting Chrome, but it also didn't work, in the end I had to completelly remove it and all profile files, and reinstall it. It seems to have worked.